# Async/Await not waiting for promise to finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have this post route:

```
  app.post("/new", async (req, res) => {
    const Lob = require("lob")({ apiKey: keys.LOB_API });

    let toAddress = await lobFuncs.toAddress(req.body.addrLine1, Lob);

    console.log("test");
  });
```

The toAddress() function looks like this:

```
toAddress: async (address, Lob) => {
    await this.parseGoogleCiv(address, obj => {
      console.log(obj);
    });
  },

parseGoogleCiv: async (address, callback) => {
    address = address
      .trim()
      .split(" ")
      .join("%20");

    let URL = "some long URL"

    await request(URL, function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        let body = JSON.parse(res.body);
        callback(body);
      }
    });
  }
```

But this is my output...

```
test
body
```

The "test" output should come after the body output.

**Question:**
What's going on here? To the best of my knowledge I think I did all the async/awaits correctly seeing as I'm not getting an promise errors. Any ideas?

Comment: the `request()` method at the end takes a callback, so it seems, it does not return a promise and hence the `await` right before it has basically no effect.

Comment: Theres a promisified version of `request` out there. Use that and kill that callback...

Comment: thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you basically await nothing in your parseGoogleCiv function. May do:

```
parseGoogleCiv: async (address) => {
  address = address
  .trim()
  .split(" ")
  .join("%20");

  let URL = "some long URL"

  try {
    return JSON.parse(
     (await new Promise((resolve,rej) =>  request(URL, function(err, res) { 
       if(err) return rej(err);
       resolve(res);
      }))).body
    );
  } catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This is probably more elegant if you use the [promisified request version](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native):

```
parseGoogleCiv(address){
  address = address
  .trim()
  .split(" ")
  .join("%20");

 const url = "someurl";

 return request(url)
   .then(res => JSON.parse( res.body ))
   .catch( err => console.log(err));
}
```